# Сделать поле input неактивным при определенном условии

Tags: html, javascript

Как сделать неактивным поле `<input type="text" />` при каком-то условии? Я полагаю, это делается через код ява...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="mytext">

<script>
if (ваше_условие) {
document.getElementById('mytext').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HcJxu/

В следующий раз, подобной сложности вопросы, поищите, пожалуйста, в поисковике..

Comment: интересно получается... написал код
<script>
if ((document.getElementById('gorod').value!='') || (document.getElementById('categories').value!='') || ((document.getElementById('gorod').value!='') || (document.getElementById('categories').value!=''))) {
document.getElementById('id_kod').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}
</script>
не получается...(( не подскажете в чем "подкол"?

Comment: @tagir, в том, что вы не знаете элементарных основ и даже javascript называете явой?

Comment: наверное, поэтому я задал здесь вопрос...